# Alternate values from two SCSS @for loops and add comma separator

Tags: for-loop, sass

So the basic gist is that I eventually want to output a zig zag clip path like so:

`clip-path: polygon(0 5px, 5px 0, 10px 5px, 15px 0, 20px 5px, 25px 0, 30px 5px );`

You can see what I have done on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/JakeGonzales/pen/MpLPOy)

I'm using an SCSS function based on one of Hugo Giraudel's [Math Sequences](http://thesassway.com/advanced/math-sequences-with-sass).

I have the code below outputting two sequences:
`5px 0px 5px 0px 5px 0px 5px 0px 5px 0px 5px` 
and
`0px 5px 10px 15px 20px 25px 30px 35px 40px 45px 50px`

These are the values that I need as you can see in the clip-path but I can't find anywhere how to flip-flop between the x-coord and y-coord with the separator to make that final step.

Is that even possible or do I need to come at this from a different angle?

```
@function zigzag($n) {

    $x-coord: 0px; // +5 each time
    $y-coord: 5px; // flip flop 5, 0, 5, 0

    @for $i from 1 through $n { 



        $last-x: nth($x-coord, length($x-coord));
        $new-x: $last-x + 5;

        $x-coord: append($x-coord, $new-x);



        $last-y: nth($y-coord, length($y-coord));
        $new-y: null;

        @if $last-y == 5px {

            $new-y: $last-y - 5px;

        } @else if $last-y == 0 {

            $new-y: $last-y + 5px;

        }

        $y-coord: append($y-coord, $new-y);

    }

    @return $y-coord $x-coord;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for the `comma` separator

```
@mixin zig-zag($n){
  $l: ();  // list to hold $x $y pairs
  $x: 0;   // increment by 5
  $y: 5px; // flip flop 5 or 0
  @for $i from 1 through $n {
    // append both $x and $y to the list using comma as separator         
    $l:append($l, $x $y, comma);  
    $x: $x + 5px;             
    $y:if($y==0, 5px, 0);
  }
  clip-path: polygon($l);
}


// test
.class {
  @include zig-zag(7);
 }


// output
.class {
   clip-path: polygon(0 5px, 5px 0, 10px 5px, 15px 0, 20px 5px, 25px 0, 30px 5px);
}
```

Comment: I've updated the Codepen with your solution http://codepen.io/JakeGonzales/pen/MpLPOy